# How to infer instances in Protégé with a minimum property restriction of a defined class?

Tags: properties, rdf, owl, ontology, protege

I'm needing some explanation for an assignement.

I'm modeling a ontology for restaurants. The classes relevant to this question are `dishes` and `Restaurant`.

The class `dishes` contain subclasses with the sort of dishes they serve. So for example `class(dishes) has subclass(italian)`. To the subclass `italian` I've added instances like `spaghetti`.

The class restaurant contains mostly subclasses with necessary and sufficient restrictions to describe the type of restaurants based on the dishes they serve. But before a restaurant can get categorised I've got create instances with named restaurants. Take for example instance(pizzaFreddi) which is linked to the instance pizza through a property hasDish. Because the instance Pizza belongs to italian the restriction on one of the defined subclasses of restaurant (with ItalianDishes) infers this instance. This one works, I've used a some restriction. But what I want to do is also create a defined subclass that infers instances(namedRestaurants) that have for example more than one location. The instance `PizzaFreddi` for example is linked with a property isLocatedIn to the city `Amsterdam` and `Den Haag`. I've made a restriction that says: isLocatedIn min 2 City. But this does not seem to infer the instance `PizzaFreddi`. What's going wrong?

I've added screenshots for explanation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sYNV.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z8rT6.png

Answer (score 2):

You have `Equivalent Restaurant and min 2 hasLocation`, it should be enough to have `SubClassOf min 2 hasLocation` as you already have Restaurant as a superclass. Also, `Equivalent` has sometimes nonintuitive consequences - I cannot tell if in this case it is a problem without the ontology.

Also, check the inferred hierarchy and make sure you're using a reasoner. If you made changes after the reasoner was started, make sure to flush the reasoner so successive changes are seen.

Comment: Alright, when I just add an subclass to restaurent and restrict it with: isLocatedIn min 2 City, it will not automatically infer the instances that meet the requirements. Thats why I made it a defined class which resultated that there came extra statement at the equilevant to.

Comment: Can you share the ontology so it's easier to debug?